# AngularJS constant configuration

Tags: angularjs

I have a function attached to my `$rootScope`

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope','$location', function($rootScope,$location){

    $rootScope.myFunction = function(){
     //do something
    };

}]);
```

I need to move `myFunction` to `angular.constant`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just registering it as a `constant`, using `angular.constant(name, function)`:

```js
angular.module('example', []);

angular.module('example')
    .constant('myFunction', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  return 'foobar';
}

angular.module('example')
    .controller('ExampleController', ['myFunction', ExampleController]);

function ExampleController(myFunction) {
  this.text = myFunction();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">{{vm.text}}</div>
</div>
```

However, while you can register anything as a `constant` (functions, objects...), note that its purpose is to save few application wide constants like the host-domain. For actual business logic, I would always recommend to use `angular.service`, to group functionality into meaningful modules.

Comment: Wonderful, works perfectly. But if i have 3 constant functions i will inject my controller with 3 functions (myFunc1,MyFunc2...). And also how to do i add $location in MyFunction() in the example you gave. I am a new to AngularJS so sorry if my questions sound too newbie.

Comment: @user3052526 You should create a `angular.service` instead, put your functions in it and inject the service where you need it. You can inject `$location` like anything else, using the array syntax I used i the example above injecting myFunction

Comment: Oh cool, so the service becomes the constant nice. Thanks @LionC